# Multiple User Type Login Through Single Login Page Issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on php and mysql code on making access to different pages based on the role of the user, through one Login Page.

Its working good for 'admin' page ..

but not able to login with 'normal type'

Little Help is really appreciated, Thank You

Here is my Code

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'dbcon.php';

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = '$username' AND user_pass = '$password'";

  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) ; 

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

      $count=mysqli_num_rows($result)  ;

         if ($count == 1) {   

            if($row['user_type'] == 'admin')
           {
             header('Location: user_registration.php');
              $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
               $_SESSION['user_login'] = $row['user_login'];
                $_SESSION['password'] = $row['user_pass'];
           }

           elseif($row['user_type'] = 'normal')
           {
             header('Location: index.php');
           }

           else
           {
            echo "WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD";
           }
        }

   }
?>
```

Comment: You said "Here is my Code", and then your question ended. I think you forgot the code.

Comment: Please add code for more detail on ur issue.

Comment: The code is vulnerable to sql injection - use prepared statements and probably use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` also depending upon PHP version.

Comment: `elseif($row['user_type'] = 'normal')` use `==`

Answer (score 0):

Move your session code after if condition and then redirect. Also is there any specific reason to store password in session. == missing

Use proper filters for inputs.

```
           if ($count == 1) { 
               if(!empty($row['user_type'])) {  
               $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
               $_SESSION['user_login'] = $row['user_login'];
               //$_SESSION['password'] = $row['user_pass'];
               }
            if($row['user_type'] == 'admin')
           {
             header('Location: user_registration.php');

           }

           elseif($row['user_type'] == 'normal')
           {
             header('Location: index.php');
           }

           else
           {
            echo "WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD";
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic test for the `normal` user was using a single `=` sign which sets a value rather than tests for equality - it needs to be `==`

Also, I think the `WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD` wa at the wrong level - it needs to be the `else` to the record count

```
<?php

    session_start();

    include 'dbcon.php';

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = '$username' AND user_pass = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($count == 1) {
            if($row['user_type'] == 'admin') {
                header('Location: user_registration.php');
                $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
                $_SESSION['user_login'] = $row['user_login'];
                $_SESSION['password'] = $row['user_pass'];
            /* require `==` here */
            } elseif( $row['user_type'] == 'normal' ) {
                header('Location: index.php');
            } else { 
                die('unknown/unhandled user level');
            }
        /* changed location of this by one level */
        } else {
            echo "WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is function for login.

It presumes password come from user with `sha512` encryption (see js libs like https://github.com/emn178/js-sha512) - it's good for non-encrypted connections.

It uses [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)), and have some protection from `brute force`, `CSRF`, `XSS` and `SQL-injection`.

```
static public function db_login($email, $p)
{
    if ($stmt = Site::$db->prepare(
        "SELECT id, password, salt, name
         FROM user
         JOIN contact ON contact_id = id
         WHERE email = ?
         LIMIT 1")
    ) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $db_password, $salt, $name);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt
        $p = hash('sha512', $p . $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts
            if (self::checkBrute($user_id) == true) {
                // Account is locked
                $res['code'] = 0;
                $res['reason'] = 'trylimit';
                $res['message'] = 'You try too many times. Come back on 30 minutes';
                return $res;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $p) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.

                    // CSRF
                    $user_browser = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_USER_AGENT', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);

                    Login::sec_session_start();
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = htmlspecialchars($email);
                    $_SESSION['name'] = htmlspecialchars($name);
                    $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $p . $user_browser);
                    session_write_close();

                    // Login successful
                    $res['isLogined'] = 1;
                    $res['code'] = 1;
                    $res['name'] = $name;
                    $res['id'] = $user_id;
                    return $res;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    Site::$db->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time) VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    $res['code'] = 0;
                    $res['reason'] = 'pass';
                    $res['message'] = 'Wrong password';
                    return $res;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            $res['code'] = 0;
            $res['reason'] = 'user';
            $res['message'] = 'We have no such email';
            return $res;
        }
    }
    $res['code'] = 0;
    $res['reason'] = 'SQL-error';
    return $res;
}
```